# Converting Collections with Collections

Tags: java

I am trying to do this following code:

```java
Map<Node, TreeSet<String>> childrenNodes = new TreeMap<>(getAll());
```

I put `getAllNodesAndEdges` method header below:

```java
public Map<Node, Set<String>> getAll() {...}
```

I need to convert a general map and the set inside of it into both `TreeMap` and `TreeSet` for sorted printing. However, the first piece of code has a compile error saying `"Cannot infer type arguments for TreeMap<>"`

What is the best way to fix this?

**Edit:more info below**

In `Information.java`:

```java
public Map<Node, Set<String>> getAll() {
        return this.all;
}
```

However, `test1.java` needs to use the code

```java
 Map<Node, HashSet<String>> all = getAll()
```

and `test2.java` needs to use the code

```java
Map<Node, TreeSet<String>> childrenNodes = new TreeMap<Node, TreeSet<String>>(getAll());
```

but both run type mismatch compile errors

the first:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Map<Node,Set<String>> to Map<Node,HashSet<String>>
```

the second:

```
The construtor TreeMap<Node,TreeSet<String>>(Map<Node,Set<String>>) is undefined
```

Comment: You need type arguments within `<>`. They cannot be inferred automatically, just as the error says

Comment: Or you could make `getAll` return a TreeMap on its own

Comment: @cricket_007 how would I do this?

Comment: Also, getAll needs to return a Map because some other classes will convert to HashMap and HashSet

Comment: Can you show the rest of the code and explain a bit more what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create new objects for the new map's values.

```
Map<Node, TreeSet<String>> converted = new TreeMap<>();

for(Entry<Node, Set<String>> entry : childrenNodes.entrySet()){
   converted.put(entry.getKey(), new TreeSet<>(entry.getValue()));
}
```

Comment: Decided to use this solution because it was best for my implementation, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this in such way.

You can do either:

1) change type of variable `childrenNodes`:

```
Map<Node, Set<String>> childrenNodes = new TreeMap<>(getAll());
```

i.e. not `Map<Node, TreeSet<String>>`, but `Map<Node, Set<String>>`

either

2) make `getAll()` return type

```
Map<Node, TreeSet<String>> getAll()
```

---

The error of compiler tells you exactly this thing: it is impossible infer `TreeSet<String>` from `Set<String>`. It is ***roughly saying*** the same as trying such kind of assignment: `HashMap<String> foo = getMap();` where `getMap()` returns simply `Map<String>`.

Comment: My dilemma is, I need childrenNodes to be a Map<Node, TreeSet<String>> because of its necessity for sorted strings. However, sometimes the returned value needs to be set to Map<Node, HashSet<String>>. So if there is no way to do this, is it just best to create another method, one that returns TreeSet, one that returns Hash<Set>?

Comment: Right, you can't do such thing. It like saying: I want variable by `Map<String>`, but some time put there integer values. Actually, you *can* do that, but forget about type variables, use raw types. Or, use most basis type (in you case it is `Set<String>`).

Comment: @PatrickParker sorry, for whom is this messages addressed? For me or for Michael?

Comment: Andremoniy / @Michael - I have added a complete answer to explain what I had meant by my comment

Answer (score 0):

You can't just cast one type of Set (TreeSet, HashSet) into another. You need to pass a supplier, e.g. `TreeSet::new`, via method parameter.

```
private final Map<Node, Set<String>> all;

public <S extends Set<String>, M extends Map<Node, S>> M getAll(Supplier<M> mapFactory, Supplier<S> setFactory) {
    return all.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
            Map.Entry::getKey,
            e -> e.getValue().stream().collect(Collectors.toCollection(setFactory)),
            (v1, v2) -> v1, 
            mapFactory));
}
```

Then you would call it like this:

```
Map<Node, HashSet<String>> test1 = getAll(HashMap::new, HashSet::new);
Map<Node, TreeSet<String>> test2 = getAll(TreeMap::new, TreeSet::new);
```

Or better yet, use the Sorted interfaces rather than implementation classes for your local variable type:

```
Map<Node, Set<String>> test1 = getAll(HashMap::new, HashSet::new);
SortedMap<Node, SortedSet<String>> test2 = getAll(TreeMap::new, TreeSet::new);
```